# Error when getting options of Select element in Python Selenium

Tags: python, html, selenium, select, drop-down-menu

I am trying to list the possible options in this Select element.

```
<select id="sl_coursePage" onchange="document.frm.submit();" name="sl_coursePage">
    <option selected="selected" value="0"></option>
    <option value="1"></option>
    <option value="2"></option>
    <option value="3"></option>
    <option value="4"></option>
    <option value="5"></option>
    <option value="6"></option>
    <option value="7"></option>
    <option value="8"></option>
    <option value="9"></option>
    <option value="10"></option>
</select>
```

I can find the element itself fine with `elem = driver.get_element_by_name('sl_coursePage')`, but then when I tried to list the options by using `elem.get_elements_by_xpath('.//*')` or `elem.get_elements_by_tag_name('option')`, it gives me empty lists.

So then I tried to use `Select` from `selenium.webdriver.support.ui` and get the list by the following code:

```
elem = driver.get_element_by_name('sl_coursePage')
select = Select(elem)
list = select.options
```

However, when I try this, it raises this error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.UnexpectedTagNameException: Message: Select only works on <select> elements, not on <input>
```

I don't understand how this is not a Select element when its tags say "select". If anyone can get any of these methods to work or present a functioning alternative method, I would be extremely grateful. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like there is an *another element with the same name* which is not `select` and get matched by the "by name" locator. Improve the way you locating the element *explicitly* asking for `select` element with the desired name:

```
elem = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('select[name=sl_coursePage]')
```

Or, checking the `id`:

```
elem = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('select#sl_coursePage')
```

Comment: Thanks so much! That did the trick. And thank you for the fantastically quick reply as well!

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to fetch the element by name

```
elem = driver.get_element_by_name('sl_coursePage')
```

Try to fetch it from id or a css selector instead, something like

```
elem =driver.findElement(By.id('sl_coursePage'))
```